# Linux Networking - "ip X" instead of ifconfig/route/etc?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm used to using commands such as `ifconfig`, `route` and so forth on linux to check and change network information. However I know there is an `ip` command (with various subcommands). I heard somewhere this is 'The right way' now. Any particular reason why I should ditch ifconfig/route/etc? What's your preference? Is there anything one set can do that the others can't?

Comment: Found a quick comparison for the basic tasks here: http://www.tty1.net/blog/2010-04-21-ifconfig-ip-comparison_en.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you cannot access more advanced iproute2 features [ for instance [multiple routing tables](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-rule.html), routing based on src address or filter ] using ipconfig+route.

for me syntax of **ip** is much more logical and easier to use.

Answer (score 11):

The command `ip` belongs to the collection of utilities called [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Iproute2).

Their manifesto:

> Most network configuration manuals
>   still refer to ifconfig and route as
>   the primary network configuration
>   tools, but ifconfig is known to behave
>   inadequately in modern network
>   environments. They should be
>   deprecated, but most distros still
>   include them. Most network
>   configuration systems make use of
>   ifconfig and thus provide a limited
>   feature set. The /etc/net project aims
>   to support most modern network
>   technologies, as it doesn't use
>   ifconfig and allows a system
>   administrator to make use of all
>   iproute2 features, including traffic
>   control.

In short it combines a number of different legacy interfaces and provides access to newer features such as policy based routing. With the benefit of a more consistent command set.

Comment: And the disadvantage of a command set that most people don't already know. Unless you need features only in iproute, or are likely to, you're as well staying with route/ifconfig.

Comment: True. Quite whether `net-tools` will ever be truly deprecated seems open for interpretation. I would say go with whatever your distro favours though. That way you won't be shocked if `net-tools` does disappear and you can avoid instances such as `ifconfig` ignoring interface addresses that were administered with `ip addr`.

Comment: ifconfig and route (and netstat) are not going to ever go away as long as UNIX as a whole continues to use them: variants from Solaris to HP-UX to AIX and beyond are still using these tools, and they are available on non-UNIX systems such as Windows.  The ip utility - though quite nice - is only available on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

iproute will eventually supersede ifconfig et al. currently there is little difference, but the syntax of ip is (at least for me) way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig and route are available on all Unixes under the sun (oh oh oh) since 1985 or so (and even on non-unixes, route exists under windows too). ip is overall better, but still uncommon except on recent linux distros. So what? know both ways and hope that everyone will switch to ip soon :)