# Why isn't ifconfig available in Ubuntu Docker container?

Tags: docker

With the base `ubuntu:12.04`, `ifconfig` is not available in the container, though the `ip` command is available, why is this? and, how to get `ifconfig` in the container?

Comment: See [Linux Networking - “ip X” instead of ifconfig/route/etc?](http://serverfault.com/q/42047/126632) and [Should I quit using Ifconfig?](http://serverfault.com/q/458628/126632)

Comment: I am aware that `ifconfig` is somehow deprecated, but some programs still depend on it.

Comment: Are the developers still alive? This was deprecated years ago.

Comment: There is bug when using `ip` in the current version of the software. I need a quick workaround of the problem.

Comment: "Some programs" and "there is bug": can you be more specific?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can install ifconfig with `apt-get install net-tools`. (Specifically, by adding `RUN apt-get install -y net-tools` to your Dockerfile.)

Based on my test, ifconfig is included in ubuntu:14.04.

Comment: Still makes me wonder why it's not included by default, but I suppose the point of this container is that it's as minimal as it possibly can be and still work.

Comment: Another addendum--on a fresh instance of the Ubuntu container the package lists are not populated either, so you must run `sudo apt-get update` if you haven't already.

Comment: `ifconfig` is not included in `ubuntu:16:04`.

Comment: To answer @Iguananaut: An Ubuntu VM is 500+ MB, whereas an Ubuntu Docker image is less than 100MB. Guys creating containers images need to draw a line as to what packages/binaries should be included and what not, so as to keep only the basic necessities inside. You know, all of this makes more sense if you think containers as processes, and not as an 'isolated computing environment to play inside and about'

Comment: I like your `happy profile picture`. \o/

Comment: will recommend to install telnet as well  (apt-get install telnet)  for testing port and host

Answer (score 13):

Unless and until you can install net-tools, there is no need to give it by default. Also if you want to see the IP address then there is another command available by docker itself:-

```
docker inspect <container_name or container_id>
```

[docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) syntax: `docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]`

This cmd will show you every detail of running container including IP address.

Answer (score 5):

I also stumbled on this nuisance, but as Devendra wrote in [docker inspect](https://serverfault.com/a/803877/415347) you can get all details about the container without `net-tools`.
In my case I needed the container's IP.
To extract the IP you can use:

```
docker inspect <container-id> \
  | grep "\"IPAddress\"" -m 1 \
  | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
```

**EDIT** even shorter notation to get container's IP (see [docker inspect examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#examples)):

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container-id-or-name>
```

Comment: This will however not work inside the container, as the  OP requested.

Comment: You're right. Just seem like a useful tip, and I thought that OP was most likely also looking to find the container's IP.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it using

```
apt-get install net-tools
```

or if you are using redhut linux install it using yum package manager

```
yum install net-tools
```